# Removing part of text using VBA (Outlook 2010)

Tags: vba, outlook

I currently use a macro in Outlook that takes the attachment name and uses that as the Subject.

The macro is:

```
Sub AttachmentNameAsSubject()

Dim AttachmentName As String
Dim currItem As Object

Set currItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

With currItem
    If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        AttachmentName = .Attachments.Item(1).DisplayName
        .Subject = AttachmentName
    End If

End With
End Sub
```

The attachment is typically some kind of .pdf or .xls file, so if the attachment is: "MyAttachment.pdf", the subject line will read "MyAttachment.pdf".

Is there a way to remove any text after the period in the subject line so that the Subject line simply reads "MyAttachment", and does not include the ".pdf" or whatever the extension may be.

Comment: You an use the Left function:  Left(.Attachments.Item(1).DisplayName, Len(.Attachments.Item(1).DisplayName) - 4)

Comment: if the extension may be more than 4 characters then you could use InStr to get the location of the period:  Left(.Attachments.Item(1).DisplayName, InStr(1, .Attachments.Item(1).DisplayName, ".") - 1)

Comment: It just depends on the extension. Most the time I feel like the extension is 4 characters (including the period, like ".pdf"). Other times it may be 5-7 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is more simpler (drops anything from the last period).

```
Function DropExtension(sName As String) As String
    If InStr(1, sName, ".", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        DropExtension = sName ' No file extension
    Else
        DropExtension = Left(sName, InStrRev(sName, ".") - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm curious, if I wanted to move keep this existing functionality, but also now add the attachment name into the body of the email, how would I do that?

Comment: You can use `.Body` or `.HTMLBody` if it's an mail item. Most item types has the `.Body` that you can manipulate.